# How to use bitmapdata.draw to get a specific area of the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm using a bitmapdata.draw(stage) to draw the stage as a bitmap but I would like to draw an area which is 32 pixels left of the stage instead, so that the area I am drawing as a bitmap is no longer in the viewing window, but the bitmap being draw is (so the stage is a bitmap). How do I draw a specific area with multiple bitmaps and display objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very nice article that can help you: http://www.tomauger.com/2013/flash-actionscript/actionscript-3-bitmapdata-draw-offset-and-positioning

You should basically use a Matrix and work your way around with it :)

My honest advise would be not to use such odd techniques as if you want to draw something it should be within the stage..